# Python Turtle mainloop() usage

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, turtle-graphics, event-driven

I have the following code from an [online tutorial](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/events.html#an-example-state-machines) to learn event-based programming by making a stop light that changes state when the mouse is clicked. Here is the entirety of my code:

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(400,500)
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Tess becomes a traffic light!")
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
tess = turtle.Turtle()

def draw_housing():
    tess.pensize(3)
    tess.color("black","darkgrey")
    tess.begin_fill()
    tess.forward(80)
    tess.left(90)
    tess.forward(200)
    tess.circle(40, 180)
    tess.forward(200)
    tess.left(90)
    tess.end_fill()

draw_housing()

tess.penup()
tess.forward(40)
tess.left(90)
tess.forward(40)
tess.shape("circle")
tess.shapesize(3)
tess.fillcolor("green")

state_num = 0

def nextFSMstate():
    global state_num
    if state_num == 0:
            tess.forward(70)
            tess.fillcolor("orange")
            state_num = 1
    elif state_num == 1:
            tess.forward(70)
            tess.fillcolor("red")
            state_num = 2
    else:
            tess.back(140)
            tess.fillcolor("green")
            state_num = 0

wn.onkey(nextFSMstate, "space")
wn.listen()
turtle.mainloop()
    # example says wn.mainloop() but I get error. This works though
```

In the tutorial, they use:

```
wn.mainloop()
```

But I get the error:

```
File "stopLights.py", line 51, in <module>
    wn.mainloop()
AttributeError: '_Screen' object has no attribute 'mainloop'
```

and have to use

```
turtle.mainloop()
```

Why the difference? I am using Python 2.7 in Ubuntu; the example is in PyScripter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be an error in the tutorial.

On line 4, they define `wn = turtle.Screen()`, which means that the later call to `wn.mainloop()` is equivalent to calling `turtle.Screen().mainloop()`.

This doesn't make any sense; as the error message states there is no `.mainloop()` method of `turtle.Screen()`. There *is*, however a `.mainloop()` method of the base `turtle` object, which is why calling that works.

Comment: FYI, there's no .mainloop() *method* of the turtle object -- turtle.mainloop() is a *function* call into the turtle library.  Python 2 defines mainloop() as a top level function that's a synonym for TK.mainloop -- Python 3 defines mainloop() as a Screen method (via TurtleScreen, via TurtleScreenBase), that calls TK.mainloop(), and, like many other Screen methods, is also defined (programmatically) as a top level function that invokes the method of the same name on the sole Screen instance.  Python 2 .mainloop() usage should work in Python 3 but the reverse depends on how it was invoked.

Comment: @cdlane _>>there's no .mainloop() method of the turtle object -- turtle.mainloop() is a function call into the turtle library._

Can you please elaborate on that? I thought all methods are functions associated with an object.

Comment: Python has both functions, not associated with objects, and methods that are associated with objects.  If I call `type(turtle.mainloop)`, I get 'function' but if I call `type(turtle.Screen().mainloop)`, I get back 'method'.  Define your own top level function and call `type()` on it -- what do you get?  Don't be confused by the `class` part of the `<class 'function'>` return value -- *functions* have a shared class but they still aren't *methods*.  The other confusing thing is the `turtle.` prefix, usually simply a library name, but in some code, a turtle instance obtained from Turtle()

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's an issue with the version of Python you're using being different than the version the tutorial is written for. In Python 3.5 on my system, an instance of the `turtle.Screen` class does indeed have a `mainloop` method, so the code you report as not working would do just fine.

There may be other issues with your code if you continue to use the wrong version of Python (though what you've included in the question seems to be part of the common subset of Python 2 and Python 3 other than the `mainloop` issue). I'd strongly recommend any new Python programmer start with Python 3 and only go back to Python 2 (and learn the differences between the versions) if they specifically need to use a library that hasn't been ported yet. Python 3 is the future, and library support is pretty good these days!

Comment: Makes sense. I was starting with 3, but unfortunately, had to get back to 2.7 because I have to work with older code