# Inputs for colours before and when running turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So I'm about as noob as possible. Currently trying to create a code where I input the colours of the background screen and the turtle pen before the turtle window opens up. Once the colours are selected, off it goes, draws my little triangle with the background and pen colours I selected.

when I try this:

```
colour1 = input ("what colour background would you like? ")
pen_colour = input ("choose pen colour ")
import turtle
window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor (str(colour1))
window.title ("Hello!")

tortoise = turtle.Turtle()
tortoise.color (str(pen_colour))
tortoise.pensize (10)

tortoise.forward (50)
tortoise.left (120)
tortoise.forward (50)
tortoise.left (120)
tortoise.forward (50)

window.mainloop ()
```

I can input the colours but the window never opens. I'm just left in the interpreter.

I have also tried:

```
import turtle
window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor input ("background colour?")
window.title ("Hello!")

tortoise = turtle.Turtle()
tortoise.color input ("pen colour")
tortoise.pensize (10)

tortoise.forward (50)
tortoise.left (120)
tortoise.forward (50)
tortoise.left (120)
tortoise.forward (50)

window.mainloop ()
```

this way the window opens then is adjusted as I make my selections. not quite what I'm after.
hope this question makes sense. first timer. would love feed back on better ways to improve my questions too

Comment: The first code snippet works fine for me. Second code snippet isn't valid Python syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252920/python-turtle-mainloop-usage), `window.mainloop()` should instead be `turtle.mainloop()`.

Other than this, the window is actually open, it is just hidden behind the IDLE Shell for some strange reason. You can open it by clicking on the IDLE icon in the windows taskbar, then clicking on the turtle screen.

If you were to run this in another editor such as VS Code, the window appears as normal. Very strange.

However, if you want to avoid this you can instead use [turtle.textinput()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/turtle-textinput-function-in-python/), which provides a nice window to enter your text.

Final code:

```
# I like to import all my modules at the top of the file, unless otherwise necessary
import turtle

# Using turtle.textinput() instead of python's input()
colour1 = turtle.textinput("Background Colour", "What background colour would you like?")
pen_colour = turtle.textinput("Pen Colour", "What pen colour would you like?")

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor (str(colour1))
window.title ("Hello!")

tortoise = turtle.Turtle()
tortoise.color (str(pen_colour))
tortoise.pensize (10)

tortoise.forward (50)
tortoise.left (120)
tortoise.forward (50)
tortoise.left (120)
tortoise.forward (50)

# Changed from window.mainloop()
turtle.mainloop ()
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't see the window opening up behind the other screen as it would open up in other locations with different lines of code. weird. appreciate the extra info too.